# Adding nested AND groups inside OR group from dictionary array in Fluent (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift3, fluent, vapor

How can I add clauses to Fluents query builder from inside a loop? I just want to loop through a dictionary array and add the predicates as per dictionary content. For example, for this array:

```
var data: [[String: String]] = [
        [
                "name": "Joe",
                "email": "joe@example.com"
        ],
        [
                "name": "John",
                "email": "john@example.com"
        ]
]
```

I would want to produce this query:

```
var contacts = try Contact.makeQuery().or { orGroup in
        try orGroup.and { andGroup in
            try andGroup.filter("name", "Joe")
            try andGroup.filter("email", "joe@example.com")
        }
        try orGroup.and { andGroup in
            try andGroup.filter("name", "John")
            try andGroup.filter("email", "john@example.com")
        }
}.all()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do:

```
var contacts = try Contact.makeQuery().or { orGroup in
    try data.forEach { inner in
        guard let name = inner["name"], let email = inner["email"] else {
            throw SomeError
        }
        try orGroup.and { andGroup in
            try andGroup.filter("name", name)
            try andGroup.filter("email", email)
        }
    }
}.all()
```